# how to keep the locale the same as the prevoius page in spring webflow?

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

I am using spring webflow for a two page app. Users enter some value in the first page (a form) and then they can see some results in the next page. If they change the language in the first page (from ENGLISH to FRENCH) they should see the results in the same language in the next page. But for some reasons it doesn't keep the locale when redirecting to the second page. Is there any special way to sole this problem in spring webflow? I appreciate any help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: also it would help to see your flow xml files